# Make pointer to point on another C program

Tags: c

If I have C program called A with the following code:

```
int main()
{
   int x=5; 
   int *pX=&x;
   return 0;
}
```

`pX` point to address of `x`, Let's say is `0x123456`.

And I have another program called B:

```
int main()
{
   int y=5; 
   return 0;
}
```

And let's say the address of `y` is `0x123488` how does the  mechanism (virtual memory) that prevent me to change the value of `pX` to point on `0x123488` (address of `y`) and to read/change the value of `y` from program A if I know the address of `y` work?

NOTE: Let's assume I debug both programs and I know the **current** address for each value.

Comment: [The virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) the OS allocates per process does the prevension.

Comment: And, it might not even be the same on each run (address space randomisation).

Comment: @WeatherVane, True, read my NOTE.

Comment: @MikeCAT but how does its actually work?

Comment: `x` and `y` might have the same address, but be at different physical locations. One isn't even accessible from the other, anyway.

Comment: duplicates: [change a pointer of address of another application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18326876/995714), [What is virtual memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58386924/995714)

Comment: How do you start the programs? You may can alloc shared memory and then execute the other program via `fork()`. Do you have a single executable for both programs?

Comment: On what platform are you? Does it have an MMU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And let's say the address of y is 0x123488 which mechanism prevent me
> to change the value of pX to point on 0x123488 (address of y) and to
> read/change the value of y from program A if I know the address of y?

It is the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space).

Meaning that while your code sees the address of `y` to be `0x123488` that is only the virtual address of y in the context of your program. The actual physical address is managed by the OS(more specifically, the kernel).

However the good news is that you can change the variable of another process. All of the interaction between two processes must be done through your OS's API.

A lot of debugging programs and game cheats use this method to debug or well, cheat at the game(do not attempt, the anti-cheat will detect this method and ban you)

For windows you can use [WriteProcessMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-writeprocessmemory) and [ReadProcessMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory). I don't know how to do it on Linux but I am sure there is a way.

Also as onVal mentioned in his answer, you should look up [Inter Process Communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) as it might be more useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Each process has a virtual address space, that's independent from each other. If you want two different processes to communicate look up [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)

The kernel takes care of this, by actually allocating in different parts of memory the two programs, and then providing each process the illusion of having their own memory (virtual memory)

If you want to know the very details of how this abstraction is implemented, I'd suggest you to read the chapter on 'Address spaces' (13) and 'Address translation' (15) from the book [Operating system: three easy pieces](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/).

It's free!

Comment: That is only if your OS uses an MMU (ok, that is probably the case in 99% of systems). But even then, you can probably alloc some shared memory, for example via `mmap()` and `MAP_SHARED`. Shared memory is a form of IPC.